# WordPress Multisite, custom wp-content folder, and Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm writing a WordPress plugin which uses the settings API from within a class. So the class calls register_settings(), add_settings_field(), and add_settings_section() from within the class which is working well except when I try to submit the form a get a server error with the following error in my logs:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

My WordPress install is a bit weird. It's based on [Mark Jaquith's WordPress Skeleton repo](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) and I have moved my wp-content folder, my wp-config.php file outside WordPress.

I am also running WordPress through Vagrant so it might be a server config issue. However, I just tried to use my plugin in VVV using a standard WordPress install and its working perfectly.

My WordPress directory looks like this (composer install WP to the app dir):

```
index.php
wp-config.php
wp-content/
app/
```

I have added my rewrite logs in a paste bin: http://pastebin.com/QKCFjULZ

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]


RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) /app/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /app/$2 [L]


RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Options -indexes
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I've narrowed it down to not being an issue with the class. I moved all the settings API functions outside the class and loaded them in the standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redirection loop because of these rules

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) /app/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /app/$2 [L]
```

Actually, you have to keep in mind that your rules are evaluated even after a rewrite. Thus, if you have `/something/wp-xxx/yyy/zzz` it will be internally rewritten to `/app/wp-xxx/yyy/zzz`. But now, as you can see, your rule will match again with new uri `/app/wp-xxx/yyy/zzz`.

Proof, looking at your logs

```
applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*)' to uri 'wp-admin/network/options.php',
rewrite 'wp-admin/network/options.php' -> '/app/wp-admin/network/options.php',
```

Then you have

```
applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*)' to uri 'app/wp-admin/network/options.php',
rewrite 'app/wp-admin/network/options.php' -> '/app/wp-admin/network/options.php',
```

And it goes on and on... until the limit of 10 redirections

To avoid this behaviour, you need to add some restriction on your rules in order to make sure they won't be evaluated when they don't have to. A simple workaround would be to use a negative lookahead pattern to make sure current request does *not* begin with `/app/` before rewriting it:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!app/)[^/]+/)?(wp-.+)$ /app/$2 [L]
```

Finally, your htaccess could look like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rule 1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?files/(.+)$ wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# Rule 2
RewriteRule ^((?!app/)[^/]+/)?(wp-.+)$ /app/$2 [L,QSA]

# Rule 3
RewriteRule ^((?!app/)[^/]+/)?(.+\.php)$ /app/$2 [L,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Reminder: the 3 rules are executed only on non-existing files/folders.

Examples:

- `http://domain.tld/files/something` or
  `http://domain.tld/xxx/files/something` will be internally rewritten
  to `/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=something` thanks to *Rule 1*
- `http://domain.tld/wp-something/somethingelse` or `http://domain.tld/xxx/wp-something/somethingelse` (where `xxx` can be anything except `app`) will be internally rewritten to `/app/wp-something/somethingelse` thanks to *Rule 2*
- `http://domain.tld/file.php` or `http://domain.tld/xxx/file.php` (where `xxx` can be anything except `app`) will be internally rewritten to `/app/file.php` thanks to *Rule 3*

Comment: Thanks for this, Sorry I missed the reply. So the rules you added didn't resolve the recursion error.

I did notice that the url in the browser never changes to include /app so

Just for my own knowledge what does the RewriteCond mean? if %{THE_REQUEST} contains that pattern, then substitute with /app?

Comment: Reading back your question again, i noticed something and modified the code in my answer. Please read examples in the bottom carefully and tell me if it corresponds to the behaviour you're expecting. Anyway, no matter what, you should **not** have loops anymore with this code

Comment: Thanks! No my recursion errors, and the site is way faster.